# Performance hit from simple change to query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I used to have a simple query that joins 2 tables by name and date.

table A:

```
Name    Date       Field1    Field2    Field3    ....
Abc     05-Apr-15  ...       ...       ...       ...
```

table B:

```
Name    Date       Field1    Field2    ....
Abc     01-Apr-15  ...       ...       ...
```

Query:

```
select a.*, b.*
from tableA a
outer apply
  (select top 1 *
   from tableB b
   where b.name = a.name
   and b.date < a.date) x
```

This query takes about 1 sec to run.

Since there are discrepancies in the name field in the 2 tables, I created a reference table to standardize the name. So I build a query like the following:

```
select a.*, b.*
from tableA a
left join refFile ref
  on a.name = ref.aName
outer apply
  (select top 1 *
   from tableB b
   left join refFile ref
    on b.name = ref.bName
   where isnull(ref.stdName, b.name) = isnull(ref.stdName, a.name)
   and b.date < a.date) x
```

Now this new query takes about 5 min to finish.

I would like to know is there a more efficient way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Without any details I would say the problem is "isnull(ref.stdName, b.name) = isnull(ref.stdName, a.name)", since that can't use any indexes because you have function in the SARG. Maybe you could fix / add the correct names to the tables?

Comment: We need to see the execution plan but as James said first attempt is to avoid using functions in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: try to change the where clause to this: `ref.stdName = a.name or ref.stdName = b.name or a.name = b.name`. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) for more info

Comment: When you use a function in where clause, IsNull in this case, query degrades. Try by adding 'and' conditions with 'is not null' check

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without an execution plan as others mentioned but here try this out:

```
select a.*, b.*
from tableA a
left join refFile ref
  on a.name = ref.aName
outer apply
  (select top 1 *
   from tableB b
   left join refFile ref
    on b.name = ref.bName
   --It's not recommended to use functions in the where clause
   --because it wont use your indexes
   --where isnull(ref.stdName, b.name) = isnull(ref.stdName, a.name)

   --try this instead.
   WHERE (ref.stdName IS NULL AND A.Name = B.name)
   OR (ref.stdName IS NOT NULL)
   AND b.date < a.date) x
```

Also why do you have TOP without an ORDER BY? It's recommended to use them together to ensure consistent results.

Comment: Superb Stephan, This is the good replacement for isnull function in the where clause. I appreciate the logical thinking. Anyhow we have to check the execution plan of this query to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

i assume your `refFile` table looks like that:

```
create table refFile
( stdName varchar primary key
, aName   varchar 
, bName   varchar
)
```

part 1 . looks ok

```
select a.*, b.*
from tableA a
left join refFile ref on a.name = ref.aName
```

part 2 . you join `refFile` again, why? and there is no relationship with part1 of your query except that `b.date < a.date`. on top of that, there is no table `b` outside that part, which means your `b.*` in part 1 can't work.

```
outer apply (
  select top 1 *
    from tableB b
    left join refFile ref
    on b.name = ref.bName
   where isnull(ref.stdName, b.name) = isnull(ref.stdName, a.name)
   and b.date < a.date) x
```

suggested part 2:

```
outer apply (
  select top 1 b.*
    from tableB b 
    where B.name in (ref.bName, ref.stdName)
      and b.date < a.date
    order by b.date desc
) b
```